# summing over a new variable in joint distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

I have noticed some examples when evaluating a joint probability they introduce a new variable by summing over it. For example:
$P(A,B) = \sum_{C} P(A,B,C) = \sum_{C} P(A|B,C) P(B,C)= \sum_{C} P(A|B,C) P(B|C)$
What is the name of this approach ? and when do we use it ?
My second question is that shouldn't the above equation be further factored to P(C)? like this:
$P(A,B) = \sum_{C} P(A,B,C) = \sum_{C} P(A|B,C) P(B,C)= \sum_{C} P(A|B,C) P(B|C) P(C)$
Or is it ok to stop whenever we want ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- This is known as [marginalization](http://planning.cs.uiuc.edu/node434.html).

If you know $P(A, B, C)$ and you intend to compute $P(A, B)$, then we can use the technique.

That is if you have $P(X, Y)$ but you are interested in $P(X)$, then you obtain $P(X)$ by computing $$P(X)=\sum_y P(X,y).$$

- You are right that they made a mistake, it should be $\sum_C P(A|B,C)P(B|C)P(C)$.